# The volume element determined by some inner product and orientation

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, multilinear-algebra

While solving the problem 4-7 in Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds", I came up with a hypothesis which can be helpful for solving the problem. The following is the problem which I'm trying to solve:

> Every non-zero $w \in \Lambda^n(V)$ is the volume element determined by some inner product $T$ and orientation $\mu$ for $V$.

Also, the following is the hypothesis:

> Let $V$ be a vector space such that $\dim V=n$ and $w \in \Lambda^n(V)$, which is non-zero. Then there exists a basis $\{v_1, \cdots, v_n\}$ for $V$ such that $w(v_1, \cdots, v_n)=1$.

My proof of this hypothesis is as follows:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow V$ be an orthogonal transformation such that $$f^*w=\det$$
and $e_1, \cdots , e_n$ be the usual basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then we observe that $f$ is invertible and thus an isomorphism by putting $f^{-1}=f^T$; $f^T$ is the transpose of $f$.
Hence $f(e_1), \cdots, f(e_n)$ is a basis for $V$. Moreover, according to the definition of $f^*$, $f^* : \mathcal{J}^n(V) \rightarrow \mathcal{J}^n(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a linear transformation such that $$f^*T(v_1,\cdots,v_n)=T(f(v_1),\cdots,f(v_n))$$
for every $T \in \mathcal{J}^n(V)$ and $v_1,\cdots,v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Therefore,
$$\det(e_1,\cdots,e_n)=f^*w(e_1,\cdots,e_n)=w(f(e_1),\cdots,f(e_n))=1.$$

---

In this proof, I'm not sure that there does exist such $f$; i.e. does there always exist an orthogonal transformation $f$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $V$ such that $f^*w=\det$ for every vector space $V$ such that $\dim V=n$ and $w \in \Lambda^n(V)$? If someone provides some ideas about this question to me, I appreciate it.

Comment: As of now, the proof doesn't make sense. You say "let $f$ be an orthogonal..." Remember that orthogonality/isometry is defined for linear maps between inner product spaces. But what is the inner product you're using on $V$? You haven't defined this (the hypotheses only tell us $V$ is real vector space; so you have to prescribe by hand an inner product). Also, you haven't defined an orientation for $V$.

Comment: Then if the inner product and orientation for V are appropriately defined as you said, can it make sense?

Comment: actually, you don't even have to talk about $\Bbb{R}^n$. Once you have the basis such that $\omega(v_1,\dots,v_n)>0$, define an inner product on $V$ using the basis, and also define the orientation using the basis.

Comment: @Rioghasarig the question is to prove that every non-zero volume form on $V$ is the unique volume form determined by some inner product and orientation (and this last phrase has a specific meaning as defined in Spivak). So yes, the orientation is important. (what is true, though irrelevant for the question at hand, is that if we start with an oriented inner product space $V$ with the induced volume form $\omega$, then there exists an orthogonal $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $f^*\omega=\det$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo. I see. My mistake.

Comment: sorry I meant $f:\Bbb{R}^n\to V$.

Comment: For the proof of the "hypothesis", just note that since $w$ is nonzero and completely determined by its single value on a basis, for any chosen basis $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ we have $w(v_1,\ldots,v_n)=\alpha\ne0$. Now take the basis $\alpha^{-1}v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$, say.

Comment: I see. The hypothesis is proved easily like that. Above all, I caused some misunderstandings by using the word "orthogonal". My intention was that $ff^T=I$, but "orthogonal" is absurd since T is not defined.